# Creating Multiple Maps from A list of map

Tags: scala, dictionary, merge, rdd

So I have an RDD as follows:

```
RDD[(Map[DateTime, Int],  //X
     Map[DateTime, Int],  //Y
     Map[DateTime, Int],  //Z
     Map[DateTime, Int],  //P
     Map[DateTime, Int],  //T
     Map[DateTime, Int])] //F
```

Each of these represent a map for a different types such as `X,Y,Z,T,P,F`. What I want to do is to add all the values in X-Map together and add all the values in Y-Maps and so on. 
At the end I want to end up with 6 different `Map[DateTime, Int]` representing each of these types.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty straightforward:

```
rdd.reduce{
  case ((x1, y1, z1, p1, t1, f1), (x2, y2, z2, p2, t2, f2)) =>
    (x1 ++ x2, y1 ++ y2, z1 ++ z2, p1 ++ p2, t1 ++ t2, f1 ++ f2)
}
```